# C++ casting a class instance to another instance throws: No suitable defined conversion from class to class2

Tags: c++

Here is my code:

```
using namespace std;

class HuffmanTree
{
public: 
    int frequency;

    HuffmanTree(){}
    HuffmanTree(int freq)
    {
        frequency = freq;
    }

    int compareTo(HuffmanTree tree)
    {
        return frequency - tree.frequency;
    }
}

class HuffmanLeaf : public HuffmanTree
{
public:
    char value;

    HuffmanLeaf(int freq, char val)
    {
        HuffmanTree(freq);
        value = val;
    }
}

class HuffmanNode : public HuffmanTree
{
public:
    HuffmanTree left, right;

    HuffmanNode(HuffmanTree l, HuffmanTree r)
    {
        HuffmanTree(l.frequency + r.frequency);
        left = l;
        right = r;
    }
}

class HuffmanCode
{
    static HuffmanTree buildTree(int charFreqs[])
    {
        priority_queue<HuffmanTree> pq;

        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(charFreqs)/sizeof(char); i++)
        {
            if(charFreqs[i] > 0)
                pq.push(HuffmanLeaf(charFreqs[i], (char)i));
        }
        while (pq.size() > 1)
        {
            // two trees with least frequency
            HuffmanTree a = pq.top();
            pq.pop();
            HuffmanTree b = pq.top();
            pq.pop();

            // put into new node and re-insert into queue
            pq.push(HuffmanNode(a, b));
        }
        HuffmanTree c = pq.top();
        pq.pop();
        return c;
    }
}

static void printCodes(HuffmanTree tree, string prefix) {
    //assert tree != null;
    HuffmanTree* baseClass;
    HuffmanLeaf* leafClass;
    HuffmanNode* nodeClass;
    if (typeid(*baseClass) == typeid(HuffmanLeaf)) 
    {
        HuffmanLeaf leaf = (HuffmanLeaf)tree;

        // print out character, frequency, and code for this leaf (which is just the prefix)
        cout<<leaf.value<<"\t"<<leaf.frequency<<"\t"<<prefix;
    }
    else if (typeid(*baseClass) == typeid(HuffmanNode)) 
    {
        HuffmanNode node = (HuffmanNode)tree;

        // traverse left
        prefix.append("0");
        printCodes(node.left, prefix);
        prefix.erase(prefix.length()-1);

        // traverse right
        prefix.append("1");
        printCodes(node.right, prefix);
        prefix.erase(prefix.length()-1);
    }
}
```

I have no idea how to fix the issue where the lines fail

```
HuffmanNode node = (HuffmanNode)tree;
HuffmanLeaf leaf = (HuffmanLeaf)tree;
```

I know it has to do with type conversion, and i'd done research on dynamic_cast, static_cast, and the other two, I can't seem to figure out what it's asking for. Any help would be appreciated. And if there are any other issues that you spot, please let me know.

Comment: You're not invoking your base constructors properly. Read about constructor initialization lists.

Comment: You also seem to be trying to cast concrete objects rather than pointers.

Comment: @Joe what? Sure you can.

Comment: It is important to be clear on the wording of questions to help with communication. What you are getting is a compiler error, which is quite different from *throw* (which usually refers to exceptions at runtime)

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I'm not too comfortable with c++ and this is my first post on stackoverflow. I appreciate any feedback really. As long as it's constructive of course ;)

Answer (score 3):

Downcasting is illegal. A `HuffmanTree` is neither a `HuffmanNode`, nor a `HuffmanLeaf`, but the other way around.

What you're trying to do doesn't really make sense. Why would you convert a `HuffmanTree` to a `HuffmanNode` or a `HuffmanLeaf`?

Either way, to get this to **compile** (but, again, it doesn't make sense), you either have to declare conversion constructors for `HuffmanNode` or `HuffmanLeaf` or add `operator HuffmanNode()` and `operator HuffmanLeaf()` to `HuffmanTree`.

Comment: *Upcasting is illegal*?? I think you mean *downcasting* `HuffmanTree` to either `HuffmanNode` or `HuffmanLeaf` is illegal.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas downcasting, yes, that's what I said... :P

Comment: Yes, that's what I think I had read... I don't know why I wrote the comment ;)

Comment: Well there are situations that a HuffmanNode or HuffmanLeaf will get passed to the PriorityQueue that of type HuffmanTree which is why I am trying to convert Node or Leaf to Tree.

Comment: My biggest issue now is actually creating the conversion constructors for HuffmanNode and HuffmanLeaf. I have looked up different articles on conversion constructors, but not entirely sure how to go about creating one for these classes.

Comment: @tgeagleeye of course you're having issues, because the cast doesn't make sense.